# How to Edit Todo List Without Using Global Variables Functional Programming Vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, functional-programming, concatenation

How do you continually edit an array of todos while using FP? I understand that when you use array methods such as .concat() you are returning a copy of the array and not editing the original. Here is my original code that simply pushes a new todo to the todo array. This permanently changes the myTodos variable which we are trying to avoid.

```
let myTodos = []

function addTodo(newTodo) {
  myTodos.push(newTodo)
  return myTodos
}
```

I have rewritten this function as such:

```
const addTodo = (arr, todoText) => arr.concat(todoText)
```

This works just fine but I don't understand how to keep the value that is returned when I am supposed to avoid global variables. If I call this to add a second todo to my list it will only return that second todo since the var is not being stored anywhere. I feel like there is a very obvious way to work this but I just cannot seem to figure it out.

My apologies I am still very new to the programming world. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Uh, no, push and pop alter the original array

Comment: You literally have zero reason to make a wrapper method around the push method, with what you are doing.  Just push to your array

Comment: @Taplar - probably homework assignment - must be _functional_

Comment: But it's not *functional*, because it's being over complicated, :)

Comment: You're right. I misread the push documentation.

Comment: Can't you just do `addTodo(myTodos, "todo")`?

Comment: @Taplar - agree completely.

Comment: I'm very confused with this question now.  If you want to alter the original array, you use push.  If you don't want to alter the original array, you can concat and store the result in a new variable.  So.... what's the question?

Comment: I think proper question you're asking is not "how to avoid global variables", but to understand _pure_ functions, and not introducing side effects.

In original example, you're introducing side effect by borrowing `myTodos` from 
outer scope of `addTodo`. 

In rewritten code, there's no side effects, you're passing input `arr`, and return output of this a new `arr`. Which consider as [pure function](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/master-the-javascript-interview-what-is-a-pure-function-d1c076bec976#8171), showing that you didn't touch any global variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
/*
1) how to avoid global variables?
2) how to not change the original?
3) how to keep the changed

#1 - this is called an Immediately Invoked Functional Expression (IIFE for short)
   What this does is lets us create a "scope" within our script.  Variables we
   create inside it with `var` or `let` or `const`, are not global.  They will
   only exist inside the scope.
*/
    (function(){
        var originalArray = [];
        // #2 - concat does not change the original array
        // #3 - to keep the change, just store it in another variable
        var changedArray = originalArray.concat('me');
        
        // #3 - if I want to make more changes, I use the new variable
        changedArray = changedArray.concat('yet another value');
        
        console.log(originalArray);
        console.log(changedArray);
    }());
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for. I was under the impression that using a new variable to store the array was impure.